# M_PI definition?

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi guys, i cant find the definition of the constant M_PI ?

i try to understand following command :
axes_yaw_max = 90.0*M_PI/180.0;

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/27581/m_pi-definition?/) by [hmmm](https://answers.ros.org/users/1556/hmmm/) on ROS Answers with karma: 37 on 2012-02-14

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Your code looks like C(++), so I assume you are talking about M_PI in a C/C++ code file.
M_PI is defined in math.h, usually located at /usr/include/ for linux gcc.

```
# define M_PI       3.14159265358979323846  /* pi */
```

If I got your question wrong please be more specific.

---

Originally posted by [Kai Bublitz](https://answers.ros.org/users/1332/kai-bublitz/) with karma: 357 on 2012-02-14

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 5

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I'm not quite sure where it is defined, but I am pretty sure that it is supposed to be pi (3.1415...).
The formula can be reduced to 0.5*PI or an angle of 90° when expressed in radians (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Radians)

---

Originally posted by [NsN](https://answers.ros.org/users/1786/nsn/) with karma: 95 on 2012-02-14

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1